# Drag&Drop in Advanced DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a Advanced DataGrid for displaying the number of rows from the Database and one row strictly should not allowed drag option. Is is possible? Please share one sample example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this is possible. Add a dragEnter Handler to your datagrid:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="adg" dragEnabled="true" dragEnter="adg_dragEnterHandler(event)" />
```

With the following code:

protected var _draggedItem:Object;

```
            protected function adg_dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.currentTarget.hideDropFeedback(event);

                var items:Array = ds.dataForFormat("items") as Array;
                if (items != null && items.length > 0 && (items[0] is CategoryVO)) {
                    _draggedItem = Object(items[0]);
                }

                // Prevent item from being dragged
                if (_draggedItem.property == true) {
                    DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.NONE);
                    return;
                }

                DragManager.acceptDragDrop(UIComponent(event.currentTarget));

            }
```

_draggedItem.property == true is the check, if an item can't be dragged.

Comment: @Thomos: this above example is showing Draging the any Rows in advanced datagrid from one place to another place is not allowing But i need one particular row only not allowing to drag and drop.suppose I have a advanced datagrid with 10 rows.I need to allowed all the rows to draga nd drop except one.

Comment: Did you chance the line with "_draggedItem.property" to your needs? This was just an example.